# iOS - Rotate MKAnnotation on a Map using a gesture

Tags: ios, mkannotation, mkannotationview

Any ideas how I can allow the user to drop in a custom MKAnnotation and also be able to rotate it after its been placed on the map using a gesture of some sort?

Comment: Do you mean to rotate the map?

Comment: No, I mean rotate the custom Annotation. So for example, I want to place a car on the map but have the car facing the right direction instead of rotating the map.